# Duplicate entries in the calendar

Tags: gnome, google, calendar

I have a problem with the GNOME Shell calendar under Ubuntu 18.04: all my calendar entries (from Google Calendar) are duplicated.
Would anyone know why?

Thank you!

One clarification: I linked my Google Account to GNOME, but I also had windows asking for passwords from all my calendars before that.
When I suppress my Google account, the problem does not appear anymore. So I think it's the ICS that I had previously imported into Evolution. But even after removing .local \ share \ evolution \ calendar \ system \ calendar.ics, the entries are still present.

Answer (score 4):

It's working fine after deleting ~/.config/evolution/sources

Comment: But is that doing (collateral) damage?

Answer (score 1):

I found that setting `CalendarEnabled=false` and then back to `true` worked for me in the source files in `~/.config/evolution`

Answer (score 0):

I just got this problem after installing Evolution and adding my Google account using the first-run wizard.

Evolution creates several sources in `~/.config/evolution/sources` and it took me a bit of experimentation to figure out what was going on. I’m still not sure I know which is the correct way these should be ordered.

The Google account has a *parent* source. *Child* sources will have an identifier (`Parent=`) in the `[Data Source]` section. For me there were *child* sources for `imapx` and `smtp` as well as a non-child source for `OAuth2`.

```
Google account source
├─ imapx source
├─ smtp source
OAuth2 source
```

The `OAuth2` source had `CalendarEnabled=true` & `ContactsEnabled=true`.

The parent account source had  `CalendarEnabled=true` & `ContactsEnabled=false`.

The simplest solution is to just change the parent account source to have  `CalendarEnabled=false`.

As an experiment I also tried making the `OAuth2` source a child of the account source, then enabling calender/contact in the *parent* and disabling them in `OAuth2`.

This also worked and seems to make more sense to me, but I’m honestly not sure how it’s supposed to work.