# Fresh Install Ubuntu 20.04 Gnome-Clock / Calendar Corruption

Tags: gnome, evolution, clock, gnome-calendar, gnome-clocks

Does someone know how to repair / **permanently** fix the problem of duplicate / corrupted entries in the gnome clock? [These instructions reset the gnome-calendar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029500/duplicate-entries-in-the-calendar), but minutes later the problem returns.

**UPDATE**

This problem was being caused by a webcalenar that I had imported into thunderbird lightning via a provided url.  The moment I deleted the calendar and rebooted, my machine returned to 100% working order.

I consider this a TEMPORARY solution, as I actually do need the to have the calendar in my ubuntu.  So I will try different ways of importing the calendar to see if the problem comes back.

Preliminarily, I think the problem may have something to do with language encoding of the calendar as it is being provided by a China based company and as far as I know Ubuntu should be compatible with icalendar files.

**Symptoms:**
1.) Slows down entire performance of gnome shell.
2.) Causes intermittent freezing, requiring reboot

This is the problem:
[image]

But after I run `sudo rm -r ~/.config/evolution/sources` the clock looks like this:

[image]

Clearly its not practical to run `sudo rm -r ~/.config/evolution/sources` every 10 minutes.

Anyone have a more permanent solution?
thx

Answer (score 0):

Let's call this a "semi-answer".

It appears that gnome-calendar does not like iCalendars imported via thunderbid/lightning (68.0).

Instead, I directly imported the icalendar (url) via the gnome-calendar app and now everything seems to work flawlessly. No duplicate entries, so slow desktop boot, etc.. Just a perfectly functioning fresh install of 20.04